# Inject AngularJs service used in run closure for testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to test an angularjs service called **MyService**. If I try to inject it,  seems that angular tries to use it before is loaded. On the other hand, if I mock **MyService** via `$provide` and so on, it works but I will not have the actual object to test.

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []).run(["MyService",
            function (MyService) {

                MyService.initListeners();


             }
        ]);

    // this is supposed to be in another file
    angular.module('app')
        .service("MyService", function() {

                return {
                     initListeners: function() {
                       console.log("working")
                     }
                }
        })

}(angular));
```

The test is this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    describe("MyService", function () {

        var MyService = null;

        beforeEach(module("app"));

        beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
            MyService = $injector.get('MyService');
        }));

        afterEach(function () {
            MyService = null;
        });

        it("injection works", function () {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy(); // throws exception
        });

    });
}());
```

Comment: your question is how to get real MyService object ?

Comment: yes, I want to test MyService, but I am not being able because it is injected in `run`, so angular looks for it before it is loaded

Comment: you should do like this  beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('MyService','LINK TO CONSTRUCTOR IF ITS IN CONSTRUCTOR');
    }));

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan what do you exactly mean? could yo post it as response?

Comment: can you show your service code ?

Comment: If we go just by your code snippet, the service itself has not been declared. If the actual code has more, would help to see how you have defined your service.

Comment: I sincerely don't think that the internals of the service are making a difference, but anyway you already have its declaration

Comment: I belive it's generally a good rule of thumb to not let your services execute anything without being explicitly asked to (aka, don't do anything async or data-important at initialization). when you're testing the service, it shouldn't matter that it's been loaded.

Comment: what are you trying to test here? Can you be more specific which function and what you want to test in that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the test on a jsfiddle.

I see the order of execution with some console messages. The order of execution is the correct, as expected.

```
My service constructor
before init
MyService.initListeners()
after init
```

And the two test work correctly:

```
    it("injection works", function () {
        expect(true).toBeTruthy(); // throws exception
        expect(MyService).toBeDefined();
    });
```

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/jordiburgos/1efvof3k/

It could be your AngularJS version, Jasmine, etc...